# Use double single quotes at final of string concat

Tags: javascript

I have simple string like this:

```
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = "All Rights reserved, ©" + n + " Company S.A. DE C.V.";
```

Problem is I want to end string with double quotes like this:

```
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = "All Rights reserved, ©" + n + " Company S.A. DE C.V."";
```

So I want to get:

> All Rights reserved, © 2018 Company S.A. DE C.V."

instead of

> All Rights reserved, © 2018 Company S.A. DE C.V.

but I get error when I use two double quotes:

```
';' expected, Unterminated string literal
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = '"All Rights reserved, ©' + n + ' Company S.A. DE C.V."';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this using `double quotes(")` inside `single quotes` ('')

```
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = 'All Rights reserved, ©' + n + ' Company S.A. DE C.V."';
```

Also you can escape quotes like this (\")

```
var abc ="All Rights reserved, ©" +  n  + " Company S.A. DE C.V.\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent situation to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = `All Rights reserved, ©${n} Company S.A. DE C.V."`;
```